# Make bootstrap carets appear in IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I checked our site in IE8 now and realized that carets no longer show up for some reason. I copy and pasted the example below from the official bootstrap documentation, but looking at it in IE8 the caret won't appear. If some recent update broke carets in IE8, is there any way to get them back?

Here are [screenshots](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/40d8e690eb74383adaa28a951cbba4817b804b3c) from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5998/) of the problem in IE8-IE10 (carets only missing in IE8).

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Button <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The triangular `.caret` element is created with a CSS triangle. It seems like changing the `border-top-style` of the `.caret` from `dashed` to `solid` fixes the issue for IE8:

```css
.btn .caret {
  border-top-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Button <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! I actually found the issue as well and posted it as an issue https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16172